# SSRS Case Statement

Tags: reporting-services, case, ssrs-2016

I have created a table in SSRS of various grades, but I need to look at the value of 2 grades together and assign it an alternate grade. I cannot put this as a CASE in the SELECT as the way the database is designed the values are not stored in one row, but in multiple rows, therefore it cannot combine the data in a new column. For example, this is one students grades represented in the DB

```
    634 Attainment  *@1@2@3@4@N/A   NULL    1   2
636 Effort  A*@A@B@C@N/A    NULL    A   2
637 Focus   EX@ME@WB@N/A    NULL    EX  1
638 Participation   EX@ME@WB@N/A    NULL    ME  2
639 Groupwork   EX@ME@WB@N/A    NULL    ME  2
640 Rigour  EX@ME@WB@N/A    NULL    ME  2
641 Curiosity   EX@ME@WB@N/A    NULL    ME  2
642 Initiative  EX@ME@WB@N/A    NULL    ME  2
643 Self Organisation   EX@ME@WB@N/A    NULL    ME  2
644 Perseverance    EX@ME@WB@N/A    NULL    ME  2
```

I have created a table that has grouped the grades based on the pupil ID and it is now represented as  one row and column headings for each grade (effort, Focus etc).

I have tried to do a sum using the ReportItems!Textbox1.Value but I can't use this method as it is not an aggregate function. What I wanted to do was

IF (ReportItems!Textbox104.Value + ReportItems!Textbox105.Value = 2) THEN 5

Is there a way to do this?

ADDITIONAL:
I have just tried:

```
=SWITCH(ReportItems!Textbox104.Value + ReportItems!Textbox105.Value = 2, 5, 
ReportItems!Textbox104.Value + ReportItems!Textbox105.Value = 3, 4, 
ReportItems!Textbox104.Value + ReportItems!Textbox105.Value = 4, 3,
ReportItems!Textbox104.Value + ReportItems!Textbox105.Value = 5, 2,
ReportItems!Textbox104.Value + ReportItems!Textbox105.Value = 6, 1,
ReportItems!Textbox104.Value + ReportItems!Textbox105.Value = 7, 0,
"NULL"
)
```

This is returning an Error.

Comment: `IIF(ReportItems!Textbox104.Value + ReportItems!Textbox105.Value = 2, 5, /*else_part*/)` didn't work for you?

Comment: It works if I do just 1 IIF statement, but I need to compare multiple values, so I changed to a switch, but this produces an error. I really don't understand why?

Comment: Your SWITCH statement would have worked but there was a bug. the last line when you stated "NULL" should read `True, "NULL"`. The SWITCH statement uses pairs of Expression, ReturnValue. The last line did not have an expression to evaluate, by adding True, "NULL" that last line will act like and `ELSE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved this by using this expression:

```
=IIF(ReportItems!Textbox104.Value + (ReportItems!Textbox105.Value = 2), 5,
IIF(ReportItems!Textbox104.Value + (ReportItems!Textbox105.Value = 3), 4,
IIF(ReportItems!Textbox104.Value + (ReportItems!Textbox105.Value = 4), 3,
IIF(ReportItems!Textbox104.Value + (ReportItems!Textbox105.Value = 5), 2,
IIF(ReportItems!Textbox104.Value + (ReportItems!Textbox105.Value = 6), 1,
IIF(ReportItems!Textbox104.Value + ReportItems!Textbox105.Value = 7, 0, 
"NULL"))))))
```